# Flutter ListView with widgets in a List doesn't updates when it should

Tags: listview, flutter, dart, setstate

I am trying to store Widgets to build by a ListView in a global List like this:

```
List<Widget> globalList= [];
```

Im trying to build a Listview in the state of a stateful class like this:

```
ListView(
  children: globalList
)
```

Now im trying to render this Listview everytime, when an item is added to the list. The function i use for this is:

```
void addList(){
    setState((){
      Widget _widget = new Widget();
      list.add(_widget);
    });
```

The Widget (in my pseudocode called `_widget`) is also a Stateful widget. But when i call `addList`, my stateful widget does not update. Why?

Shortended (Pseudo)-Code:

```
List<Widget> globalList = [];

class STFUL extends StatefulWidget{

  @override
  _STFULState createState() => _STFULState();
}

class _STFULState extends State<STFUL>{
  void addList(){
    setState((){
      Widget _widget = new Widget();
      globalList.add(_widget);
      });
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body:ListView(
      children: globalList
    )
  }  
}
```

Below there is a button to call addList. My problem is, that the ListView doesn't renders the updated list, when I call setState.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `ListView.Builder` in place of your `ListView`,

Comment: Yes you are right. Just take the length of the list for the itemCount property and then return globalList[i]  in the builder. Thank you very much for the hint!